# Change the table display of list items

Tags: blog

I am trying to change the OOTB display of list items to this [image]

Which is the way the blog posts are displayed in Summary View; However the Summary View look cannot be applied to a custom view.

Ultimately, I just need to figure out how to rearrange the table cells to look like the picture.

Comment: The announcement list has a Summary View which pretty much looks like the way you want it.. And I think it is customizable in SharePoint Designer..

Comment: It is; however, if I take a list, create a custom view (ie. My Post) then try to change the display to Summary View like the one above, it includes all of the posts an not just 'My Posts' anymore.

Comment: What if you create a view using SharePoint Designer itself, first to the view look and feel customization and than apply filters or grouping etc.?